# chai.assert.isRejected Message validator not working

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm attempting to write the following test:

```
return chai.assert.isRejected(quote.validate(), 'Amount is not valid number');
```

When running this test, it is successful but upon fudging it to ensure it fails with the following, it still passes:

```
return chai.assert.isRejected(quote.validate(), '123Amount is not valid number');
```

I also tried the following:

```
return chai.assert.isRejected(quote.validate(), new Error('Amount is not valid number'));
```

But it seems to fail:

> AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected with [Error: Amount is not valid number] but it was rejected with [Error: Amount is not valid number]

I have reason to believe its failing though because they are referencing different Error instances but not 100% sure.

Ideally I would like to be able to ensure that the proper error / message is being returned but I can't seem to figure it out and was looking for some help.

** Note I am using chai-as-promised as well

Comment: Works as expected with "chai-as-promised": "6.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using expect instead of assert? I ran into the same issue when trying to use assert.

`expect(promise).to.be.rejectedWith('Error msg.').and.notify(done)`